# installing pd-extended in 14.04 says requires installation of untrusted packages and crashes software center

Tags: 14.04, software-center

I followed the instructions from http://puredata.info/docs/faq/debian

For Pd-extended releases, use the apt.puredata.info repository. To add it, run these command in your Terminal:

> sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://apt.puredata.info/releases
>   `lsb_release -c | awk '{print $2}'` main"
>
> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key
>   9f0fe587374bbe81
>
> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key
>   D63D3D09C39F5EEB   sudo apt-get update   sudo apt-get install
>   pd-extended

and I keep getting the message
"requires installation of untrusted packages and crashes software center" pd-extended

pd-extended wont install and the ubuntu software center crashes and I have to reboot. I click on repair and ok and it just loops

See image of [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WP9d.png]

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Answer (score 1):

You have omitted a space in the first apt-key. Compare it to the second. Damn that pesky whitespace. Also, stacktrace formatting probably munged the ticks out of the first line

So, here it is corrected for all us copypastas:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://apt.puredata.info/releases `lsb_release -c | awk '{print $2}'` main"

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 9f0fe587374bbe81

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key D63D3D09C39F5EEB
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pd-extended
```

Worked for me.

Comment: still doesn't work..... same error..... are you using 14.04?

Comment: I found a missing single tick, and fixed it above, maybe thats the issue? And yes, I'm on 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, Changing download source to **Main Server** solved it.

```
Software & Updates > Download from > Main server
```